# ReactJS: Change text via index from array in a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Sorry if the title is confusing. I'm not too sure how to word this.

On my index.js I have an array

```
let appts = [
{
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Scofield",
    "dob": "06-2-1972",
    "sex": "Male",
    "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at pulvinar lacus, nec consequat felis.",
    "time": "10:00 AM"
},
{
    "firstName": "Lincoln",
    "lastName": "Burrows",
    "dob": "02-17-1970",
    "sex": "Male",
    "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at pulvinar lacus, nec consequat felis.",
    "time": "10:20 AM"
},
{
    "firstName": "Sara",
    "lastName": "Tancredi",
    "dob": "06-1-1977",
    "sex": "Female",
    "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at pulvinar lacus, nec consequat felis.",
    "time": "10:40 AM"
}
```

]

In my Sidebar component, I output the array into a list item, buttons of sorts

```
let filteredAppts = this.props.appts.filter(
        (appt) => {
            let name = appt.firstName + ' ' + appt.lastName;
            return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
    );


<div className="appt-list">
    <ul>
        {filteredAppts.map((appt, index)=> {
            return <Appt appt={appt} key={index} index={index}/>
        })}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in my Appt component, I output the list item itself, and have a function that returns the index of the item that you clicked on (I was playing with things trying to get it to work)

```
var selected = 0;


handler(index, event) {
    selected = index;
    console.log(selected);
}

render() {
    return (
        <li onClick={this.handler.bind(this, this.props.index)}>
            <div className="appt-info">
                <h4>{this.props.appt.lastName + ', ' + this.props.appt.firstName}</h4>
                <span>{this.props.appt.time}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="appt-excerpt">  
                <p>{this.props.appt.summary}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
```

So then inside of another component, I was the info of the appointment that you selected displayed.

```
<header className="appt-info">
                <h2>{this.props.appts[0].lastName + ', ' + this.props.appts[0].firstName}</h2>
```

I would want to replace `this.props.appts[0]` with the index of the item that was clicked on. But I'm not sure how I would transfer that `selected` variable, to the component.

My App looks like this

```
var selection = 2;

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="appContainer">
            <Nav />
            <div className="appContent">
                <Sidebar appts={this.props.appts}/>
                <Patient appts={this.props.appts} selection={this.props.selection}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


render(<App appts={appts} selection={selection}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should use Flux or Redux. Or you need the same parent for Sidebar and Header and transfer `selected` in this component.

Comment: Is `Sidebar` a child of `Appt`?  What is the component hierarchy?  I'm asking this because you need to be able to bubble up the filter change to a level that can pass it back down to `Appt`

Comment: So you have mentioned three components: `Sidebar`, `Appt`, and "another component".  Can you explain how they are related?  Do they have a common parent?

Comment: @JordanBonitatis Yeah, there is no actual component hierarchy. I guess that's where I'm going wrong. See updated post. The `var selection = 2;` was something I was messing around with to see the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bubble up your selection from the `Sidebar` back into the parent's state (`App`), which will then pass it back down to `Sidebar`'s sibling, `Patient`

We can do this by passing a reference to the parent's `handleApptSelection` which will be called when `Sidebar` changes.  You will do this by modifying `Sidebar`'s `handler` method

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedAppt: appts[0]
    }
  }

  handleApptSelection(apptRec) {
    this.setState({selectedAppt: apptRec});  
  }

  render() {
    const {selectedAppt} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="appContainer">
        <Nav />
        <div className="appContent">
          <Sidebar appts={this.props.appts} onSelect={this.handleApptSelection.bind(this)}/>
          <Patient appts={this.props.appts} selection={selectedAppt}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Sidebar's handler method:

```
handler(index) {
  const {appts, onSelect} = this.props;
  selected = index;
  console.log(selected);
  onSelect(appts[index]);  // this is actually App's handleApptSelection method!
}
```

Comment: Had to play around with it for awhile, but eventually got it working. Thanks a lot!

For the App constructor, it would giving me an error of `cannot call this before super()` or something along those lines. So put `super()` before `this.state`. Also `this.state = {}` was giving me an error of `undefined`, just made it `selectedAppt: appts[0]`, so it'll always return the first appointment when you load in. Then I was getting a `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` so googled around and found this fix: `this.handleApptSelection = this.handleApptSelection.bind(this);`

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.  I've updated my example to incorporate your notes :-)